# AngularJS filter on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I would like to filter my results.

There is a list of files which can be uploaded and next to each there is a beneficiary selection option, my wish is when 1 checkbox is checked, the selected one shouldn't be displayed in the next two field and the remaining unselected one's are to be displayed in them. [Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2gAU.png)

I'm a newbie to AngularJS, so here is my code:

```js
;(function () {
  'use strict'
angular
    .module('app.user', [])
    .controller('UserController', UserController)
    .filter('trusteefilter', function($filter){
      return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
          if(arrayFilter){
              return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
                  return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]) === -1;
              });
          }
      };
    })
    .constant('config', {  
      Beneficiary1: 'Beneficiary1',  
     Beneficiary2: 'Beneficiary2',  
     Beneficiary3: 'Beneficiary3',   
      })
```

```html
<!--Beneficiary1-->
  <td>                                
    <div class="btn-group" ng-init="getSelectedBeneficiary(value,null,null)">
      <button type="button" class="multiselect form-control dropdown-toggle btn btn-custom"
        data-toggle="dropdown" title="Columns">
        {{selectedBeneficiary[$index].Beneficiary1}}                                      
        <b class="caret"></b>
      </button>      
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">                                     
        <li ng-repeat="contact in value.Beneficiary1" id="item">                                 
          <label class="checkbox"
            ng-repeat="test in personalDetails | filter : {'_id':contact.contactId}">                         <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="contact.id" ng-model="confirmed"
              ng-click="change(value,key,test,$event,'Beneficiary1')" id="ng-change-example1">
              {{test.firstName}}
            </input>
          </label>
        </li>         
        <li ng-repeat='item in personalDetails | trusteefilter:getmytrusteeIds(value.Beneficiary1):"_id"' id="item"> 
          <label class="checkbox" ng-show="item._id">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" 
              ng-click="change(value,key,item,$event,'Beneficiary1')"
              id="ng-change-example1">
              {{item.firstName}}
            </input>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>    
    </div>
  </td>
  <!--Beneficiary2-->                            
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group" ng-init="getMySelectedTrustees2(value,null,null)">
      <button type="button" class="multiselect form-control  dropdown-toggle btn btn-custom"
        data-toggle="dropdown" title="Columns">
        {{selectedBeneficiary[$index].Beneficiary2}}
        <b class="caret"></b>
      </button>      
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
        <li ng-repeat="contact in value.Beneficiary2" id="item">                                 
          <label class="checkbox"
            ng-repeat="test in personalDetails | filter : {'_id':contact.contactId}">
            <!--{{document.getElementById("ng-change-example").checked = contact.status;}}-->
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="contact.id" ng-model="confirmed"
              ng-click="change(value,key,test,$event,'Beneficiary2')" id="ng-change-example1">
              {{test.firstName}}
            </input>
          </label>
        </li>         
        <li ng-repeat='contact in personalDetails | trusteefilter:getmytrusteeIds(value.Beneficiary2):"_id"' id="item">                                         <label class="checkbox" ng-show="contact._id">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" 
              ng-click="change(value,key,contact,$event,'Beneficiary2')"
              id="ng-change-example1">
              {{contact.firstName}}
            </input>
          </label>
        </li>         
      </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
  <!--Beneficiary3-->
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group" ng-init="getMySelectedTrustees3(value,null,null)">
      <button type="button" class="multiselect form-control dropdown-toggle btn btn-custom"
        data-toggle="dropdown" title="Columns">
        {{selectedBeneficiary[$index].Beneficiary3}}
        <b class="caret"></b>
      </button>      
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="contact in value.Beneficiary3" id="item">                                 
          <label class="checkbox"
            ng-repeat="test in personalDetails | filter : {'_id':contact.contactId}" >
            <!--{{document.getElementById("ng-change-example").checked = contact.status;}}-->
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="contact.id" ng-model="confirmed"
              ng-click="change(value,key,test,$event,'Beneficiary3')"
              id="ng-change-example1">
              {{test.firstName}}
            </input>
          </label>
        </li>         
        <li ng-repeat='contact in personalDetails | trusteefilter:getmytrusteeIds(value.Beneficiary3):"_id"' id="item">                                         <label class="checkbox" ng-show="contact._id">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" 
              ng-click="change(value,key,contact,$event,'Beneficiary3')"
              id="ng-change-example1">
              {{contact.firstName}}
            </input>
          </label>
        </li>         
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood your problem... but I think you can add a property to your Beneficiary, like $$selected and then control his visibility using ng-if.

Comment: Its simple. I can choose upto 3 benefeciaries for 1 particular file. So if i select 1 beneficiary as the 1st choice it shouldnt appear under beneficiary 2 & 3. And if i select 2 it shouldnt appear under the 3rd. @L.Figueredo

Comment: You can check the image.